# How to convert list of dictionaries to list of tuples?

Tags: python, dictionary, tuples

I have a list of dictionaries in python like:

```
lst = [{'f_id': '1', 'm_id':'22', 'fm_id':'23'},{'f_id': '2', 'm_id':'32', 'fm_id':33}]
```

I'm trying to update the values in dictionary like
lst = [{'f_id': '3', 'm_id':'22', 'fm_id':'N'},{'f_id': '4', 'm_id':'32', 'fm_id':N}]

and get only values from dictionary and put them in list of tuples like:

```
new_lst = [('3', '22', 'N'),('4', '32', 'N')]
```

I've tried:

```
list_of_dict = []
for each in lst:
    for key, values in each.items():
        temp = values
        list_of_dict.append(temp)
    print(list_of_dict)
```

but I'm getting a different output. I'm tried different approaches but not getting the expected output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried this?

```
lst = [{'f_id': '1', 'm_id':'22', 'fm_id':'23'},{'f_id': '2', 'm_id':'32', 'fm_id': '33'}]
new_lst = [tuple(d.values()) for d in lst]
```

Comment: try this `[tuple(list(d.values())) for d in lst]`

Comment: @user696969 thanks for your help. I'd like to update the values in dict before converting into tuples like [{'f_id': '3', 'm_id':'22', 'fm_id':'N'},{'f_id': '3', 'm_id':'32', 'fm_id':'N'}]

Answer (score 0):

Here is a one liner solution:

```
j=[tuple([str(x) for x in d.values()]) for d in lst ]
```

Output:

```
[('1', '22', '23'), ('2', '32', '33')]
```